# 404 Not Found in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I made an ASP.Net MVC 5 app. While debugging on my VS2013 everything runs well but when I deploy it to IIS I start to get some 404 Not Found errors. Is not in every routes but I keep getting this in some GET/POST. I already tried to add on web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ScriptCompressionModule" type="Westwind.Web.ScriptCompressionModule,Westwind.Web" />
    </modules>
```

Didn't worked and I read that it wasn't a good pratice, so I changed to:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
      <!-- Your other add tags-->
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

It's how it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently the problem was in some ajax request that I have, the url passed must use the @Url.Action helper, because the path on the IIS Server could be different, or part of it.